# Having troubles with Bootstrap scaffolding in Laravel 7.6

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4

Good afternoon.
Today I started a new job with Laravel, and as always I worked with Laravel, I choosed the Bootstrap scaffolding. But this time, the styles doesn't appear.
I know that I can just put the link in HEAD, but I never used it before in Laravel.
It's the first time that happened, and it's also the first time I work with a 7.x version of Laravel. If somebody knows where the problem may be, it would help me a lot.
I let you here an image showing an example of the problem.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

The HTML tags are with their Bootstrap classes, this is the first Navbar of the Bootstrap documentation page.

[image: Blade file]

Comment: Have you run ```npm install && npm run build```?

Comment: Yes, it's the first things I do everytime I start a new project

Comment: Have you included the ```app.js``` and ```app.css```? Also, make sure that you have them inside ```public/css``` and ```public/js``` folder.

Comment: Laravel makes it automatically, and it's all ok in their respective folders

Comment: So in that case, I think the solution is what @lewis4u mentioned below.

Comment: Laravel/ui is the first thing I require and install in my projects for the front, that's why idk where the problem can be

Comment: Can you share the blade file?

Comment: How do you load your project? locally or on a server or how?

Comment: @lewis4u I use the artisan serve command

Comment: then try to cancel it... make php artisan view:clear and then again serve and tell us what happens

Comment: @eamirgh it's done

Comment: But you never load the app.css anywhere??

Comment: You have not included the app.js and app.css files in your view

Comment: @lewis4u I'll tried it and doesn't worked. If I can't fix the problem I should put the api link, but I hate to do it

Comment: @lewis4u  I've never did it before, and it worked fine. I'll try now.

Comment: @lewis4u done and working! A lot of thanks! I've never did it before, and it worked properly. now I'll take care to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `app.css` and `app.js` file in your blade file.
Like

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: @lewis4u It worked fine! I don't know why in earlier versions I did not needed to do that and now yes. By the way, **a lot of thanks to both of you!** Now I'll have that in mind everytime I start a new project